# Test network performance of a repository ?

Tags: repository

I use the `ftp.be.debian.org` repos and since few days it seems really slow but I'm not sure if it comes from them or from me. Does a way exists to compute download rate in order to compare with other repos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a tool for debian called:

```
netselect-apt
```

it tests all the official mirrors so you can compare the speed results and make an appropriate choice.

```
apt-get install netselect-apt
```

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netselect-apt